# AJAX - Promise.all method - unexpected output dilemma

Tags: javascript, promise

My question is about why there are two expected outputs from this chunk of ajax code but when I test in the debugger/console-panel this gives me only [foo, car] as output?

```js
const a = new Promise((res, rej) => { //n1
  setTimeout(() => res('foo'), 300);
});

const b = new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setInterval(() => rej('bar'), 100);
  res('car');
});

Promise.all([a, b]).then((race) => {
  console.log(race);
}).catch((crash) => {
  console.log(crash);
});
```

Right answers:

```
[foo, car] 
['bar', 'car']
```

- why this?

Comment: Hi @user9669810 you might explain what you have tested and done to research why you expect the results ['bar', 'car']. Also, I would re-work the portion of your question that explains the "right answers" so that it refers to the expected answer and the actual answer generated. Right now it looks like you are suspecting two "right" answers from one execution. Otherwise a very nicely organized question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promises are designed to store **either** a future result (the argument to `res()` above) **or** a future error (the argument to `rej()` above) but not both.  It is therefore not valid to call both `res()` and `rej()` in a Promise body.

In this example, when trying to resolve the future values of `a` and `b`, the promise returned by `Promise.all` will call either the function passed to `then()` or the function passed to `catch()` based on the resolution or rejection of `a` or `b`.

Usually, it will call the function passed to `then()` with a list containing first values with which `a` and `b` resolved.  If either promise rejects prior to resolving, however, the promise returned by `Promise.all` will call the function passed to `.catch()`.

Since the `a` promise always resolves, and because the `b` promise **resolves first**, and does so with the value, `car`, `Promise.all([a,b])` will resolve with a value containing `car`.  It will not reject with the value `bar` because `b` resolved first.

Although the Promise implementation provided by your browser handles the double reject/resolve silently, do note that this could result in undefined behavior.  For example, some implementations of `Promise` will throw an exception when used in this way.